# Using dependency injection with typescript in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm converting a component (AngularJS 1.6) from javascript to typescript.

```
class NewProjectCtrl {
    price: number;

    static $inject = ['$http'];

    constructor($http) {
        let ctrl = this;
        ctrl.price = '50'; 
        ...
    }

    createProject() {
        $http.post('/api/project', ctrl.project)
        ...
    }
}

angular
    .module('app.projects-selection')
    .component('newProject', {
        templateUrl: 'app/projects-selection/components/new-project/new-project.tmpl.html',
        controller: NewProjectCtrl,
        bindings: {
            user: '<',
        }
    });
```

Typescript complains on the `$http` in my createProject method (Cannot find name $http). All the examples I can find only uses dependency injections in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot `this`. After injecting use `this.$http`

Also let me suggest you some approach according to styleguides:

```
namespace myNameSpace {

  class NewProjectCtrl {
    private static $inject = ['$http'];

    public price: number;

    constructor(private $http) {}

    createProject() {
      this.$http.post('/api/project', ctrl.project)
    }
  }

  class NewProjectComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    constructor() {
      this.bindings: {
        user: '<',
      };
      this.templateUrl: 'app/projects-selection/components/new-project/new-project.tmpl.html';
      this.controller: NewProjectCtrl;
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('app.projects-selection', [])
    .component('newProject', new NewProjectCtrl());
}
```

Comment: Where is this style guide? I followed the ng upgrade guide https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#switching-to-typescript . Is the guide not updated?

Comment: I use [Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/tree/master/typescript) and [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) style guides

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a class, not a mere function. `$http` is injected into your `constructor` function and exists there, but it does *not* exist in `createProject`. You need to store it on the instance as property:

```
private $http;  // should be declared first too, preferably with type hint

constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
}

createProject() {
    this.$http.post('/api/project', ctrl.project)
}
```

TypeScript has a shorthand for that:

```
constructor(private $http) {
}

createProject() {
    this.$http.post('/api/project', ctrl.project)
}
```

`let ctrl = this` also seems rather weird, I don't think that makes a lot of sense. I don't know what else you're doing in the constructor, but I'd refactor what you have to this:

```
class NewProjectCtrl {
    price: number = 50;

    static $inject = ['$http'];

    constructor(private $http) { }

    createProject() {
        this.$http.post('/api/project', ctrl.project);
    }
}
```